# Qt crashes on system call?

Tags: c++, qt, segmentation-fault, system-calls, qtcore

I have the following cpp file:

```
#include <iostream>                  
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

  int main(int,char*[])
  {
    int b = std::system("dot -Tdot ./a.dot -o ./a3.dot");
    cout << "ret: " << b << endl;
    return 0;
  }
```

Running from cmd with:

```
g++ -O2 -Wall -pedantic -pthread q2.cpp -lboost_graph && ./a.out
```

Runs fine creating `a3.dot`

Running the same file with `qtcreator` I get:

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
ret: 35584
```

This is the compiler output from `Qt`

```
make: Entering directory `/home/studnet/QtProjects/T2-build-desktop-Qt_4_8_1_in_PATH__System__Release'
g++ -c -pipe -O2 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -DQT_WEBKIT -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_DECLARATIVE_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED -I/usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/linux-g++ -I../T2 -I/usr/include/qt4/QtCore -I/usr/include/qt4/QtGui -I/usr/include/qt4/QtDeclarative -I/usr/include/qt4 -I../T2/qmlapplicationviewer -I. -I../T2 -I. -o main.o ../T2/main.cpp
g++ -Wl,-O1 -o T2 main.o qmlapplicationviewer.o moc_qmlapplicationviewer.o    -L/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu -lQtDeclarative -lQtGui -lQtCore -lpthread
```

I tried debugging it in Qt, but I am fairly new to it, and get an assembly Window. I put `a.out` in the `build` folder from where qt usually reads the file and in the source folder just in case.

Any suggestions how I can fix this?

Thank you.

EDIT:

I tried this:

```
QProcess process;
process.start("dot", QStringList() << "-Tdot ./a.dot -o ./a3.dot");
process.waitForFinished(-1);
```

But then I get no file.

Comment: `Running the same file with Qt I get:` -> What does it mean "running it with Qt"?

Comment: It is still not enough. What is your project file? Are you using command line, qtcreator, or even cmake? Please provide lotta more information.

Comment: Every time someone says "system call" I get excited. Until I open the question.

Comment: @LaszloPapp qtcreator which I think uses qmake

Comment: `-I../T2/qmlapplicationviewer` -> You seem to have configured a GUI project in QtCreator. Not that it should crash, but why? Try to create a console based project. Let me know if that works...

Comment: @LaszloPapp I am using this as part of a GUI project, I isolated it so I can test it. I tried the console approach it just stays frozen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is quite when you claim "running it with Qt". I will assume you mean `qmake` at this point based on the lack of QtCreator or any other IDE tag for the question.

Not that it should crash, but you seem to have used a GUI project when creating it even though this seems to be a command line based application. This is the proof for that:

```
-I../T2/qmlapplicationviewer
```

I would encourage you to either reconfigure it or create a new one like that. Basically, the code with the project file below works fine for me.

#### main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>                  
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main(int,char*[])
{
  int b = std::system("dot -Tdot ./a.dot -o ./a3.dot");
  cout << "ret: " << b << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

#### main.pro

```
TEMPLATE = app
TARGET = main
QT -= core gui
SOURCES += main.cpp
```

#### Build and run

```
qmake && make
```

In order to reply to your lat edit:

```
QProcess process;
process.start("dot", QStringList() << "-Tdot ./a.dot -o ./a3.dot");
process.waitForFinished(-1);
```

This is wrong. You will need re-read how the start method works:

[void QProcess::start(const QString & program, const QStringList & arguments, OpenMode mode = ReadWrite](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/qdoc/qprocess.html#start)

You need to pass the arguments as string list, rather all the arguments as a string within a string list. Thereby, the correct code would be something like this:

```
QProcess process;
process.start("dot", QStringList()
                      << QString("-Tdot")
                      << QString("./a.dot")
                      << QString("-o")
                      << QString("./a3.dot"));
process.waitForFinished(-1);
```

Please note that for either of two approaches, you may need to use the correct path rather than the one assumed to be in the folder where the application is rum from as it is currently presented in both snippets.

You could try to use absolute paths either statically or dynamically by [getting the application dir](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/qdoc/qcoreapplication.html#applicationDirPath) from the application instance. Alternatively, you could also [set the working directory](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/qdoc/qprocess.html#setWorkingDirectory) on the QProcess instance.

This is especially important when it comes to for instance QtCreator because the IDE tends to change the build directory to a custom one not to produce the build files beside the source files for having a clear separation. If you do not do this, the files might still be generated by your invoked process, but not in the source directory where you would look for it, but the build directory.

Comment: @Laszio Papp thanks for the answer, I duplicted what you had, the cmd still crushes. Even if did this work I still need this as part of a GUI application.

Comment: @mihajlv: please stop talking about the gui part. It is irrelevant AFAICT. Furthermore, I cannot reproduce the crash at all, so I believe you really have either not provided all the necessary details, or not replicated the setup appropriately. You might have problem with your custom `dot` command. We really cannot know without lotta more details and context. You have not even shared the Qt and QtCreator versions.

Comment: @Laszio Papp, What you have works,however I have to run the exe from the folder in order to get `a3.dot`. What I am trying to do is produce `a3.dot` and then read it in after the system call. I think I have to look at QProcess for the gui part.

Comment: @mihajlv: I also posted the QProcess in my solution before... Please take a look at that. Also, please note that QProcess is in QtCore, not QtGui, so no need of GUI for that...

Comment: @Laszio Papp, I was just looking at that :), I did as: `process.execute("dot", QStringList() << "-Tdot" << "./a.dot" << "-o"<< "./a3.dot");` the only problem is that it is not creating the file when when I run the program from qtcreator, however when I start the exe from cmd it works fine ... any ideas on what is going here?

Comment: @mihajlv: do not use execute; use start. execute is a static method, and you will not be able to get the object data later if you get used to it. Specify full path to ./a.dot and ./a3.dot rather than relative because QtCreator is changing the working directory, or look for the file created in the build directory. Failing that, get the error string by process.errorString() and paste it here.

Comment: I just tried `start` still not creating the file when running from qtcreator